# product of all argument and absolut values of matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a complex matrix A (NxN). In Matlab eig(A) will give me all the complex eigenvalues of the matrix. Now I am interesting in finding the absolute value (r) and the argument (\phi) of each complex eigenvalues (each eigenvalue has its own r=abs(Z) and \phi=arg(Z)) .
How can I write the following product expression:

\prod_j (sin(\phi_j)+r^(1/2)_j  where the index j run over all the eigenvalues of the matrix A.

Answer (score 0):

To get `r` and `phi`, simply use the Matlab functions `abs` and `angle`, like so ...

```
z = eig(rand(5));
r = abs(z)
phi = angle(z)
```

Then you can do whatever you need to do with the resulting vectors.

---

For example, the product of the quantity `sin(phi) + sqrt(r)` for all `phi` and `r` pairs would be:

```
prod(  sin(phi)  +  sqrt(r)  )
```

(Note, vectorization of the `sin` and `sqrt` function removes the need for any looping.)

Comment: Thank you for that. I have a question if, suppose I have a vector
V=(v1,...vn) how can I compute the product: \pi_j(sin(v_j)) where j run from 1 to n? did u understand my question?

Comment: As well as I understand your initial question, I have added additional content to the answer.

Comment: Thanks Pursuit I got the idea.